# Type hinting function parameter - PHP

Tags: php, laravel, type-hinting

This question is not about a programming logic but a good practice that should be followed.

In my new Laravel project I started defining type for function parameter as I think it's a good habit.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
public function test(Collection $data, array $arr, int $num)
{
    // My code
}
```

In above code I defined type of `$data` parameter as `Collection` because I know it's going to be collection only. But after reutilizing this function I realize this parameter `$data` could be instance of any other collection class and I have to type hint all classes in order to make function work properly otherwise it will throw error

```
Expected parameter of type 'Illuminate\Support\Collection', 'other collection instance' provided
```

When I execute a query I get instance of `Eloquent\Collection` class, when I `paginate()` a query I get instance of `LengthAwarePaginator` class and suppose I passed my collection through resource API then I will get the instance of `AnonymousResourceCollection` class.

If I'm going to type hint this much of class then it will be untidy and looks messy.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection as S_Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection as E_Collection;
use \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator as Paginator
use \Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\AnonymousResourceCollection as R_Collection

public function test(S_Collection|E_Collection|Paginator|R_Collection $data array $arr, int $num)
{
    // My code
}
```

You might have understood by now what's the problem. Even I make alias of each class it still looks messy.
I don't want to use `mixed` otherwise it will accept all type of arguments.

I want to know is there any better and clean way of doing it so when anybody including you look at your code they don't feel annoyed and frustrated?

Comment: I don't know the class structure of all of these classes, but do they have some common interface which they all implement which you could define as the parameter type?

Comment: If you find yourself doing this then maybe your function is responsible for too many things (breaking the single responsibility principle). A resource collection and a collection are similar only in name. They are used completely differently

Comment: @NigelRen I was hoping for the same but it looks they don't have common interface.

Comment: I suppose all of them implement `ArrayAccess` so you could do `ArrayAccess $data`.

Comment: Are the collection classes based on an abstract class?
Then you can use this classname as typehint